# How to set user in LinuxContainerExecutor

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a long running application master that accepts requests (monitors queue). In request i have a field "username" - the user, i want to launch a job on a container from.

As from yarn documentation:

> The default value set for Apache Hadoop in non-secure clusters is org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor. This class runs all containers as the Yarn user to avoid accidental operations being executed in the NodeManagers by arbitrary users.
>
> The alternative value for this property is org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor. This class executes containers with the container-executor binary, which performs a privilege escalation to run containers as the users that submitted the application request.

I've changed yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class to LinuxContainerExecutor. Also set yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.nonsecure-mode.limit-users to false. How can i set a user which will be run command on a container? The only method that seems like does authentification is ContainerLaunchContext.setTokens. I have a next code:

```scala
private def setupTokens(user: String): ByteBuffer = {
    val ugi = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser(user, UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser)
    LOG.info(s"Creating proxyuser ${ugi.getUserName} impersonated by ${UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser}")
    val credentials = ugi.getCredentials
    val dob = new DataOutputBuffer();
    credentials.writeTokenStorageToStream(dob);
    ByteBuffer.wrap(dob.getData(), 0, dob.getLength()).duplicate();
}

val cCLC = Records.newRecord(classOf[ContainerLaunchContext])
cCLC.setCommands(List("whoami"))
cCLC.setTokens(setupTokens(user))
nmClient.startContainer(container, cCLC)
```

But it still executes as user that's running AM, rather than specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RM will grant tokens only to the app-ID requesting it (and the true owner thereof), it's impossible also run an App with the AM as one user and Containers as another.